# SQL displaying results as columns from rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

SQL Noob here.

I realize that many variations to this question have been asked but none seems to work or be fully applicable to my annoying situation, ie. I dont think `PIVOT` would work for what I require. I cant fathom the necessary words to google what I need efficiently.

I have the following query:

```
Select w.WORKORDERID, y.Answer
From 
[SD].[dbo].[WORKORDERSTATES] w
LEFT JOIN [SD].[dbo].[WO_RESOURCES] x
ON  w.workorderid = x.woid
Full Outer Join [SD].[dbo].ResourcesQAMapping y
ON x.UID = y.MAPPINGID
WHERE w.APPR_STATUSID = '2'
AND w.STATUSID = '1'
AND w.REOPENED = 'false'
```

It will bring back the following result:

```
+-----------+---------------------+
| WORKORDER |       Answer        |
+-----------+---------------------+
|     55693 | Brad Pitt           |
|     55693 | brad.pitt@mycom.com |
|     55693 | Location            |
|     55693 | NULL                |
|     55693 | george              |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

I would like all rows related to the value 55693 to output as columns like below:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+----------+--------+--------+
| WORKORDER |  VALUE1   |       VALUE2        |  VALUE3  | VALUE4 | VALUE5 |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+----------+--------+--------+
|     55693 | Brad Pitt | brad.pitt@mycom.com | Location | NULL   | george |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+----------+--------+--------+
```

There will always be the same amount of values, and I am almost sure that the solution involves creating a temporary table but I cant get it to work any which way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know which value goes in which column?  SQL tables and results sets with no `order by` are *unordered* .

Comment: PIVOT is exactly what you require, together with ROW_NUMBER

Comment: Please show your attempt to use PIVOT, and what was wrong with the result.

Comment: Table schemas would go a long way toward helping here. We don't know how to distinguish your proposed columns without knowing what data points are available to leverage. Good tools & examples here: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2):

If you always have the same number of values (5) you can use a static `PIVOT`, otherwise you need a dynamic TSQL statement with `PIVOT`.

In both cases you'll need to add a column to guarantee rows/columns ordering otherwise there is no guarantee that you'll see the correct value in each column.

Here is a sample query thet uses a static `PIVOT` on 5 values (but remember to add a column to properly order the data replacing `ORDER BY WORKORDER` with `ORDER BY YOUR_COLUMN_NAME`):

```
declare @tmp table (WORKORDER int, Answer varchar(50))

insert into @tmp values
 (55693, 'Brad Pitt')
,(55693, 'brad.pitt@mycom.com')
,(55693, 'Location')
,(55693, 'NULL')
,(55693, 'george')

select * from
(
  select 
     WORKORDER, 
     Answer,
     CONCAT('VALUE', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WORKORDER ORDER BY WORKORDER)) AS COL 
  from @tmp
) as src
pivot 
(
  max(Answer) for COL in ([VALUE1], [VALUE2], [VALUE3], [VALUE4], [VALUE5])
)
as pvt
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to select another column that has different values as answer column and try to run pivot and that will work